# $\int\int_{D}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dx \ dy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, surface-integrals

Given the next domain $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 :1\leq x^2+y^2\leq4,0\leq y \}$ I have to compute this integral: $$\int\int_{D}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dx \ dy$$

I know that $x=r\cos\phi$ and $y=r\sin\phi$ and $x^2+y^2=r^2$, but this is not enough. Can somebody help me,please?

Comment: Can you try applying Fubini's theorem knowing that $D=(0,2)\times(-\pi,0)$? (resp. the domain of $r$ and of $\phi$).

Comment: Why is the domain of $\phi$ $(-\pi,0)$? and how will $dx,dy$ change?

Comment: You also need the "element of area" $dx\,dy = r\,dr\,d \phi$.

Comment: ah sorry I misread it. should have been $(1,2)\times(0,\pi)$ (corresponding to the answer of Dave).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: use polar coordinates. This is the integral of $\frac{1}{r^2}$ over the upper semi-circle of radius $2$ minus the upper semi-circle of radius $1$.

Comment: It's fair to also point out that the Jacobian here from Cartesian to Polar coordinates makes the integrand $1/r$.